# Global variables and module importing

Tags: python, module, global-variables

I've been using Python for years, and creating new modules for distribution is still confusing and eludes me; and it is REALLY frustrating.  I need an expert to explain this.

I recently discovered that setting a global variable in a sub-module behaves differently depending on how the module is imported in the `__init__.py` file.

I have something like this set up:

prime.py

```
 import sub
 sub.somevar = False
 sub.show()
```

sub.py

```
somevar = True
def show():
    global somevar
    print("somevar is {}".format(somevar))
```

This code produces the expected output:

```
somevar is False.
```

*when main.py and sub.py are in the same directory*.  When I make `sub` a separate installable module with setuptools, it stops working.

My `sub` installable module directory structure looks like this:

```
# ls
setup.py sub README.md
# ls sub
__init__.py sub.py
```

Where `__init__.py` contains the text:

```
from .sub import *
```

This setup appears to work great for installing and distributing the module, for both Python2 and Python3.

The problem is that now global variable setting is broken when I import it with `prime.py`; any attempt to set `somevar` from `prime.py` does not change the variable for functions of `sub.py` as is intended.  I get the output:

```
somevar is True
```

What the hell is going on here?  Why is python module importing so finicky?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not related to your project structure, but only how you import it.

I think it is easy to understand. As `somevar` is a value type when you use `from x import *` which implicitly `from x import somevar`, you get a copy of `somevar` in your current namespace.

And because it is just a copy, changing it won't change the `somevar` in your submodule.

But if `somevar` is a list, like:

```
# In sub.py
somevar = [True]
```

And you change it by

```
# In prime.py
somevar[0] = False
```

Then it will work.

Comment: Is there a "right" way to do the `sub` module installation?  Is it bad practice to use `from .sub import *` in the `__init__.py`?

Comment: Yes, that is a bad practice.

Comment: Great - what should I do instead?  What should `__init__.py` contain in a "proper" setup?

Answer (score 0):

For quick fix, you can simply use "setter" "getter" behavior:

prime.py

```
import sub
sub.set_somevar(False)
myFalseVar = sub.get_somevar()
```

sub.py

```
somevar = True
def get_somevar():
    global somevar
    return somevar

def set_somevar(var):
    global somevar
    somevar = var
```